# Unable to insert element before and after (both) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using jQuery 3.x. I am trying to append a dynamically created element before and after an element using `insertBefore()` and `insertAfter()`. However, only `insertBefore()` is working, and another one is ignored. When I am commenting one then other is working. why?

```js
p = $("<p></p>").text("This is a dynamicly created element");
p.insertAfter($('nav'));
p.insertBefore($('nav'));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header,
nav,
main,
aside,
footer {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid mediumseagreen;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background: dodgerBlue;
}

nav {
  background: mediumSeaGreen;
}

main {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

main,
aside {
  height: 1200px;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
}

div::after {
  content: " ";
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

main {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  This is header
</header>

<nav>
  This is navbar
</nav>

<main>
  <article>
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum atque fuga, eos neque ipsum enim id inventore necessitatibus laboriosam quo nobis, repellendus maxime veritatis error ut expedita, velit aspernatur asperiores!
    </p>
  </article>
</main>

<aside>
  This is side bar
</aside>
<div></div>
<footer>
  This is <a href="http://">footer</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `p` references only a single element. You insert it in to the DOM in the `insertAfter()` call, then move the same element to a new location using `insertBefore()`.

To do what you require you can `clone()` the element before the second insertion. Also note that you don't need to create an entire jQuery object to select `nav`, you can just pass the selector as a string. Try this:

```js
let p = $("<p />", { 
  text: "This is a dynamicly created element"
});
p.insertAfter('nav');
p.clone().insertBefore('nav');
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header,
nav,
main,
aside,
footer {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid mediumseagreen;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background: dodgerBlue;
}

nav {
  background: mediumSeaGreen;
}

main {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

main,
aside {
  height: 1200px;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
}

div::after {
  content: " ";
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

main {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>This is header</header>
<nav>This is navbar</nav>
<main>
  <article>
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum atque fuga, eos neque ipsum enim id inventore necessitatibus laboriosam quo nobis, repellendus maxime veritatis error ut expedita, velit aspernatur asperiores!
    </p>
  </article>
</main>

<aside>This is side bar</aside>
<div></div>
<footer>This is <a href="http://">footer</a></footer>
```

One other thing to mention, I would suggest researching flexbox layouts. They're a much more modern and extensible technique than forcing `display: table` on a `div` to create a multi-column layout.

Comment: But, I think element are just strings, as created in javascript as text. Am I right?

Comment: In this case, no. You create a jQuery object from the `<p />` string. You then reference that ***single*** object multiple times, hence why it gets moved.

Comment: I can get it's type using typeof operator, and I can also insert it just by initializing var p again.